# Is there any difference in the usage of ‘Samstag’ and ‘Sonnabend’, besides a geographical one?

Tags: word-usage, usage

This is what *dict.cc* says about the usage of [*Samstag*](http://www.dict.cc/?s=samstag) and [*Sonnabend*](http://www.dict.cc/?s=sonnabend):

> Samstag [bes. westd., südd.] [österr.] [schweiz.]
>
> Sonnabend [bes. nordd. und ostmitteld.]

Comment: I don't think so. http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Samstag.jpg

Comment: I only can say, that »Sonnabend« is definitely never used in Austria, and its usage will confuse Austrian people. When I heard this word for the first time in my life, I thought it would mean »sunday evening« (»Sonntag Abend«). Later I learned, that it was »the evening before sunday« (»Der Abend vor dem Sonntag«) which in fact is this words origin, and even later, I learned, that this »evening« started in the early morning and lasts all day long. So it is »the day before sunday« or just »saturday«.

Comment: They’re abbreviated differently: _Sa._ vs. _Sbd._ because _So._ is already used for _Sonntag_. That was reason enough for me to abandon _Sonnabend_. Also note that both words are usually pronounced with two syllables only (in the North): /zamsdax/ vs. /zona:mt/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No.** They are synonyms. I would argue that *Samstag* is in more common usage if you want to address an audience across all of Germany. The *Tagesschau* daily news program, although being produced in Hamburg uses *Samstag* (compare the weather forecast at the end of [last Friday’s report](http://www.tagesschau.de/multimedia/sendung/ts-14227.html)). The regional weekly newspaper in Braunschweig (*Neue Braunschweiger*) consistently uses *Sonnabend.*

I also noted that the speaker, [Jan Hofer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jan_Hofer), even though being from the North used the decidedly Southern pronunciation of *Samstag* and *28.* ending in /k/ rather than /ç/ or /x/.

There could be a tendency of Notherners to replace *Sonnabendabend* with *Samstagabend* to avoid repeating the *Abend*, but I don’t have enough data to confirm that.

Comment: The Tagesschau link will probabably be dead after two weeks, right? I have not watched it, does he really say /g/ instead of /k/? Anyway, I think that "Samstag" is the word that you use if your audience is not regional. The Berliner Verkehrsbetriebe use "Sonnabend", though, so the word is not yet dead.

Comment: @CarstenS Du hast Recht mit /k/ statt /g/. Das von wegen örtlichem Gebrauch trifft ja auch auf die Neue Braunschweiger zu ;)

Comment: Richtig, den Braunschweigteil hatte ich nicht aufmerksam genug gelesen. Ich würde aber die Aussprache nicht "decidedly southern" nennen, denn es ist die Standardaussprache, egal woher sie ursprünglich kommt.