# Do people actually use Sonnabendabend in a non-jocular way?

Tags: word-usage

*Sonnabend* is the day before Sunday, also known as Saturday.

*Sonnabendabend* then is Saturday evening (although it could have meant Friday!), as confirmed by [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Sonnabendabend) and [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Sonnabendabend).

I've seen *Sonnabend* in actual use, but *Sonnabendabend* to me sounds... funny.  Is this word in active use in serious contexts, or does the word also sound funny and would it rather be used in a slightly jocular context only?

Comment: That's why you should use "Samstagabend". :)

Comment: @FrankfromFrankfurt Well, I would use *Samstag* anyway, the first time I saw *Sonnabend* I thought it was short for *Sonntag Abend* or at best the evening before *Sonntag*, rather than the full day of Saturday…

Comment: Und Übermorgenmorgen fragen wir nach Übermorgenmorgen? Sonnabendabend kann m.E. übrigens nicht Freitag bedeuten; man sagt auch nicht 1.-Maiabend um den 30. April zu bezeichnen. Außer Sonnabend fällt mir allenfalls Heiligabend als ähnliche Konstruktion ein.

Comment: Der Tag nach Übermorgen heißt aber Überübermorgen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sonnabend is [only used in parts of Germany](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/30053/is-there-any-difference-in-the-usage-of-samstag-and-sonnabend-besides-a-geo), but where it is used, Sonnabendabend is indeed an unremarkable word. Only in writing it is a bit hard to parse.

Comment: Because of that it's often written as "Sonnabend Abend" or "Sonnabend-Abend" for better legibility.

Comment: @mtwde, I think the first is officially wrong.

Comment: You are right! At least since 1996s Rechtschreibreform the first one is officially  wrong. But you will find it in a lot of older books. I should have mentioned it.

Comment: @mtwde, don't worry, for cases in which I really want to know what the old rules prescribed, I have an old Duden lying around ;)

Comment: _Sonnabendabend_ is perfectly normal in eastern Germany, the usual pronunciation is [zona:mt aːbn̩t]